# PATINDEX with letter range exclude diacritics (accented characters)

Tags: sql, sql-server, diacritics, patindex

I am trying to figure out how to use a patindex to find a range of letter characters, but exclude accented characters.  If I do a straight search, using the default collate (insensitive) works just fine.  However, when I search a range of letters, it will match on the accented character

```
SELECT
    IIF('Ú' = 'U' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI, 'Match', 'No') AS MatchInsensitive,
    IIF('Ú' = 'U' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, 'Match', 'No') AS MatchSensitive,
    PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%', 'Ú' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI)      AS PIInsensitive,
    PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%', 'Ú' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS)      AS PISensitive
```

Will give the following results:

```
MatchInsensitive MatchSensitive PIInsensitive PISensitive
---------------- -------------- ------------- -----------
Match            No             1             1
```

What I am really trying to do is to identify the character position of accented characters in a string, so I was really searching for `PATINDEX('%[^A-Z0-9 ]%')`.

If I have the following query, I would expect a result of 2 `SELECT PATINDEX('%[^A-Z0-9 ]%', 'médico')`, but I get 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a binary collation, e.g. `Latin1_General_100_BIN2`.

```
select patindex('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', 'médico' collate Latin1_General_100_BIN2)
```

rextester: http://rextester.com/ZICLN98474

returns `2`

Comment: Thank you.  I cannot believe that I didn't think of that.  I was just so surprised that accent sensitivity didn't work.